# ScrollView Not Scrolling in 4inch iPhone

Tags: iphone, ios6, uiscrollview, scroll, autolayout

I really wonder why my `scrollview` is not scrolling when testing it in a 4 inch iPhone simulator and real iPhone 5. Everything works fine  when I run it in 3.5 inch simulator/iPhone4s.

By the way, I'm using autolayout, and upon checking the `scrollview.frame.size.width` and `scrollview.frame.size.height` via NSLogs, the values are okay but the `scrollview` is not scrolling when I run it in a 4inch simulator/iDevice.

What could be the problem? Thanks for the answers.

Comment: content visibly fully up-to or not.if not check your content size

Answer (score 0):

I think you should check nslog in scrollview size and its content size.. might be they are equal in 4 inch screen... If they are equal, then there scrollview is not allow to scroll content.

Answer (score 0):

Write only one line

```
         scrollview.contentSize = CGSizeMake(320*[arrFields count],560);
```

here arrFields are an array which contains images.....use as per your need what you want to scroll